# How do you pull standardized beta coefficients in R with categorical variables?

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, linear-model, standardization

So I have independent variables which are binary and continuous, e.g.,

$$
depression = anxiety*x + gender*x + residence*x + u
$$

So I have the `lm()` output from R, but this gives unstandardized coefficients. I'm wondering whether it is meaningful to try to get standardized coefficients with categorical independent variables?

If so, how would I do that?

I considered the following,

```
call1 <- lm(scale(depression) ~ scale(anxiety) + as.factor(gender) + as.factor(residence), d5)
```

and then `summary(call1)`. Would this be inaccurate to scale continuous variables but leave others?

Comment: Welcome to CV. Why do you want to standardize all of your variables in this setting?

Comment: ty! yep, ideally, but i dont think it makes much sense to std categoricals? so would it be better to just report unstd coeff?

Comment: What does $x$ represent in your formula? Do you intend to estimate any interactions?

Comment: You can get standardized coefficients easily enough by computing the model matrix and standardizing its columns.  But your question remains: is this meaningful?  What motivates you to seek a standardized coefficient?